# Can I use the same facebook connect api key/secret in both iphone app and website?

Tags: iphone, facebook

I have an iphone app and a website, and the iphone app can access the website's data through the api of my website.

Now, the users can sign up the website through the facebook connect. The next step of plan is that the users should sign in the iphone with facebook connect, and sync the data between the iphone and the website.

I have already got a facebook connect api key/secret for the website, the question is can I use the same key/secrete for the iphone app? and can the iphone app use the same key/secret the sign up account in the website, so that users don't have to sign up in the website again when they visit the website later?

Any advice would be grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API key you have for your Facebook application is specific to your domain name. As long as users are signing up for accounts with you through your website, whether on the iPhone or directly on the website, you can use the same API key.